# I can't understand this line in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SharedPreferencesDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreferencesDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key); <-------- This line

  @override
  SharedPreferencesDemoState createState() => SharedPreferencesDemoState();
}
```

I can understand the part before and after the colon, but what does the colon at the middle mean? I am talking about the colon sitting in between those two parts of the line. What does the line ultimately mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does super and Key does in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968561/what-does-super-and-key-does-in-flutter)

Comment: No it doesn't. I know both parts before and after the colon. But I don't understand why the colon itself is at the middle of the line. What is the purpose that it's serving?

Comment: Then you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274735/3743245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called constructor. Used to create new instance of class by calling `new SharedPreferencesDemo()` or just `SharedPreferencesDemo()`.

```
SharedPreferencesDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Here's explanation of each part.

```
SharedPreferencesDemo - constructor name
(...) - constructor arguments
{Key key} - optional named arguments
: - initializer list, used to call super or initialize variables including final ones
super - calls parent constructor (StatefulWidget.StatefulWidget)
key: key - sets value of optional argument [key] for parent constructor
```

Initializer list is used to initialize final variables or call constructor with specified arguments. Here's another example:

```dart
class AuthClient {
  AuthClient({ String username, String password }) :
    _token = '$username:$password';

  final String _token;
}
```